# NLog.config copied to root and bin directories

Tags: asp.net, nlog

I have just installed **NLog** (version 4.4.11) on a classic **ASP.NET** website and set `Build Action = Content` and `Copy to Output Directory = Copy if newer` for the NLog.config file, [as told on the wiki](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting).

Problem is when I **publish** the website from Visual Studio, the NLog.config file located in my Visual Studio project is copied to the root directory *and also* to the bin directory.
Only the file in the bin path is taken into account, not the one in the root directory.

**How can I remove the copy located in the root directory ?**

Is there a NLog config option available or have I to remove it on publication (if possible) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your site having issues finding the config file in the root or you just don't want it in the root?

The nlog.config should be treated like the web.config in ASP.Net sites.  Set it to content but not copy to output.  It will exist in the root with the web.config.  Copying to output is for console or other application types where the config exists with the other files. ASP.Net should read the config files from the root.

NLog.config [search locations](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file)

Comment: I was asking to remove it from the root, but considering what you said: it should be in the root, not in the bin, as the Web.config file. I thought this location would not work, but I will try it.

Comment: I was wrong: NLog.config is actually taken into account when it is located in root directory, like you said. So, I'll probably delete my question in a few days... Thanks for putting me back on track.